# How did Lupin ensure he was safe for people?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures, werewolf, remus-lupin

I mean during his transformations. We know that during his time as a student at Hogwarts he was isolated in the Shrieking Shack. When he was a teacher, he used Wolfsbane potion provided by Snape. But what about other periods of life, including his time in the Order of the Phoenix? How did he ensure he would not attack anyone?

It is worth mentioning that apparently after Lupin had left the school, Snape wasn't providing the potion for him anymore. As Lupin said to Harry to explain why he trusted Severus:

> ...But I do not forget that during the year I taught at Hogwarts, Severus made the Wolfsbane potion for me every month, made it perfectly, so that I did not have to suffer as I usually do at the full moon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Presumably, Lupin locked himself up securely.

Since 1637, the Ministry of Magic protocol for a werewolf to avoid harming humans was to have them lock themselves up securely every month.

> The Ministry of Magic’s policies on werewolves have always been muddled and inefficient. A Werewolf Code of Conduct was developed in 1637, which werewolves were supposed to sign, promising not to attack anyone but to lock themselves up securely every month. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Werewolves (WizardingWorld.com)](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/werewolves)*</sup></sub>

When Lupin did not have access to Wolfsbane Potion, he likely kept himself locked up somewhere until he returned to human form, similar to how he was hidden in the Shrieking Shack as a Hogwarts student.

Comment: One wonders if he could lock himself in a cage with the key tied to the outside so he could unlock it when he transformed back into a human. Easy enough to reach through the bars to unlock it when one has an opposable thumb, nearly impossible to use a key without one.

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, that seems like a logical way for him to lock himself away while he is in werewolf form while allowing him to free himself when he becomes human again.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing I can find explaining what Lupin did *exactly* during his transformations, but we can infer he most likely would disappear, take himself off to a remote location, and transform into a werewolf far away from other people.

We know he didn't have access to the *Wolfsbane Potion* until he started teaching at Hogwarts:

> Remus had no chance to sample it [the Wolfsbane Potion] without admitting what he was and so he continued his lonely, itinerant existence.
>
> ...He was only persuaded to accept when Dumbledore explained that there would be a limitless supply of Wolfsbane Potion
>
> <sub>[Wizarding World - Remus Lupin](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/remus-lupin)</sub>

He did have jobs before working at Hogwarts, but never kept them for very long. The following quote tells us that Remus, who is currently [living hand to mouth](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/live+hand+to+mouth), is more willing to stop working and leave without any further explanation after only a month or two than *feed himself*.

> Remus now lived a hand-to-mouth existence, taking jobs that were far below his level of ability, always knowing that he would have to leave them **before his pattern of growing sick once a month at the full moon was noticed** by his workmates.
>
> <sub>Ibid. (emphasis mine)</sub>

Additionally, even though the above passage is more about the stigma of being a werewolf in the *Harry Potter Universe*, Lupin's worry about having his monthly "habit" being recognised and leaving before being noticed is amplified when we read about his fear of biting someone else.

> It had always been Remus’s worst fear that he would kill while out of his right mind.